# Постановка знаков препинания в предложениях с общим придаточным

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли здесь расставлены знаки препинания? Я так понимаю, что запятых перед союзами "и" не нужно, т.к. здесь общее придаточное предложение "когда были неприятные рабочие моменты".

В трудные минуты, когда были неприятные рабочие моменты, я мог прийти к нему и одна его фраза все ставила на свои места и было ясно, что делать дальше.

Comment: > ...я мог **придти** к нему

ПРАВИЛЬНО: ***прийти.***

 

Comment: Да, уже исправила.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы поставил запятую, поскольку (несмотря на присутсвие объединяющей конструкции) второе зависит от наличия первого: "фраза" сделает своё дело, только если он придёт услышать её. "И" здесь по смыслу заменяется на "тогда".

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае действует правило, касающееся употребления повторяющихся союзов: при наличии общего второстепенного члена или общей придаточной части запятая перед союзом "и" ставится, если союз повторяется (Розенталь Д.Э. Справочник по пунктуации. М., 1984. С. 138). Таким образом, правильное оформление примера будет следующее: ***"В трудные минуты, когда были неприятные рабочие моменты, я мог прийти к нему, и одна его фраза все ставила на свои места, и было ясно, что делать дальше".***